# Solving a system of differential equations of order 3

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the set of differential equations

$$w_{1}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{1}-3w_{2}-\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}+\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}=0$$

$$w_{1}-\frac{d}{dt}w_{1}-w_{2}+\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}=0$$

The question is to show that every strong solution of the above can be written as $$w(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{1}-3\alpha_{2}\\\alpha_{1}\end{bmatrix}e^{t}+\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{2}\\\alpha_{2}\end{bmatrix}te^{t}+\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\\beta\end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\begin{bmatrix}\gamma\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$

In other words, I want to find a solution to $(P(\frac{d}{dt})w)(t)=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

That is

$$P(\frac{d}{dt})w=\begin{bmatrix}1+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} & -3-\frac{d}{dt}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}+\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}\\1-\frac{d}{dt} & -1+\frac{d}{dt}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_{1}\\w_{2}\end{bmatrix}(t)=0$$

I calculated $\det P(\xi)=(\xi-1)^{2}(\xi+1)(\xi+2)$, the roots of which are $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm 1$ and $\lambda_{3}=-2$, with $\lambda_{1}=1$ having multiplicity 2.

I don't know where to go from here though. I think I have to calculate the eigenvectors, but given the nature of my matrix (which is composed of $\frac{d}{dt}$ rather than constant values) it seems a bit tricky.

**Edit:** I tried taking the Fourier transform

$$\begin{cases}F(w_{1}(t))+F(\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{1}(t))-F(\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t))+F(\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}(t))+F(\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}(t))=0\\F(w_{1}(t))-F(\frac{d}{dt}w_{1}(t))-F(w_{2}(t))+F(\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t))=0\end{cases}$$

To get

$$\begin{cases}\hat{w}_{1}(f)+(2\pi if)^{2}\hat{w}_{1}(f)-2\pi if\hat{w}_{2}(f)+(2\pi if)^{2}\hat{w}_{2}(f)+(2\pi if)^{3}\hat{w}_{2}(f)=0 \\ \hat{w}_{1}(f)-2\pi if\hat{w}_{1}(f)-\hat{w}_{2}(f)+2\pi if\hat{w}_{2}(f)=0\end{cases}$$

But when I simplify, I get

$$\begin{cases}(1-4\pi^{2}f^{2})\hat{w}_{1}(f)=(2\pi if+4\pi^{2}f^{2}+8\pi^{3}if^{3})\hat{w}_{2}(f) \\ (1-2\pi if)\hat{w}_{1}(f)=(1-2\pi if)\hat{w}_{2}(f)\end{cases}$$

Which cannot be right because then we would have that $\hat{w}_{1}(f)=\hat{w}_{2}(f)$.

**Edit 2:**

**(Correction of Edit 2) Edit 3:**

For the second equation, we have $$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-t}(w_{1}(t)-w_{2}(t)))=0$$

Now, plugging in $w_{1}(t)=w_{2}(t)+ce^{t}$ into the first equation yields $$w_{2}(t)+ce^{t}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}(w_{2}(t)+ce^{t})-3w_{2}-\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}+\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}=0$$

i.e. $$\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}(t)+2\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}(t)-\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t)-2w_{2}(t)=-2ce^{t}$$

First we want to calculate the homogeneous part of the equation. That is $$\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}(t)+2\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}(t)-\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t)-2w_{2}(t)=0$$

The characteristic equation is $$r^{3}+2r^{2}-r-2=0$$ i.e. $$(r-1)(r+2)(r+1)=0$$

Hence we get the general solution: $$w_{2}(t)_{h}=C_{1}e^{-2t}+C_{2}e^{-t}+C_{3}e^{t}$$

Now I want to find the particular solution, $w_{2}(t)_{p}$. The inhomogeneous part is $f(t)=-2ce^{t}$

Take $w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}$. Then $\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-ke^{t}$; $\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-2ke^{t}$; $\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-3ke^{t}$.

$$-kte^{t}-3ke^{t}-2kte^{t}-4ke^{t}+kte^{t}+ke^{t}+2kte^{t}=-2ce^{t}$$

i.e. $$-6ke^{t}=2ce^{t}$$

So $k=\frac{c}{3}$.

That gives us the general solution $w_{2}(t)_{h}+w_{2}(t)_{p}$:

$$w_{2}(t)=C_{1}e^{-2t}+C_{2}e^{-t}+C_{3}e^{t}-\frac{c}{3}te^{t}$$

Now we plug $w_{2}(t)=w_{1}(t)-ce^{t}$ into the first equation to get

$$w_{1}(t)+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{1}(t)-3w_{1}(t)+3ce^{t}-\frac{d}{dt}w_{1}(t)-ce^{t}+\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{1}(t)-ce^{t}+\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{1}(t)-ce^{t}=0$$ i.e. $$\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{1}(t)+2\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{1}(t)-\frac{d}{dt}w_{1}(t)-2w_{1}(t)=-ce^{t}$$

The characteristic equation of the homogeneous part of the equation is $$r^{3}+2r^{2}-r-2=0$$ Again, we get $$w_{1}(t)_{h}=C_{1}e^{-2t}+C_{2}e^{-t}+C_{3}e^{t}$$

Take $w_{1}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}$. Then substituting gives $-6ke^{t}=-ce^{t}$, thus $k=\frac{c}{6}$.

So $w_{1}(t)_{p}=-\frac{c}{6}te^{t}$. Hence $$w_{1}(t)=C_{1}e^{-2t}+C_{2}e^{-t}+C_{3}e^{t}-\frac{c}{6}te^{t}$$

So we can write $$w(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1}(t) \\ w_{2}(t)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{3} \\ C_{3}
\end{bmatrix}e^{t}+\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{c}{6} \\ -\frac{c}{3}
\end{bmatrix}te^{t}+\begin{bmatrix}
C_{1} \\ C_{1}
\end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\begin{bmatrix}
C_{2} \\ C_{2}
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$

However, this is not the solution I was after.

Comment: have you tried fourier/laplace  transform.....this should transform everything into algebraic equations.the inverse transformations won't be too hard

Comment: @tired Check the edit.

Comment: The second equation reads $$(e^{-t}(w_1(t)-w_2(t)))'=0$$ hence you might want to plug $$w_1(t)=w_2(t)+ce^t$$ into the first equation and solve for $w_2$ the resulting differential equation (linear, third order, with RHS $-ce^t$, thus, entirely standard stuff).

Comment: interesting to be honest i don't now what goes wrong here (maybe because i'm a little bit wasted today). but @Did suggestion will work nicely

Comment: @Did See the second edit.

Comment: $-2w_2$, not $-3w_2$, then the roots are obvious.

Comment: @Did Why $-2w_{2}(t)$?

Comment: Because $w_2-3w_2$... Seriously, **check your computations**.

Comment: Do you believe that $(ce^t)''=ct^2e^t$? 'Cause this is what you wrote...

Comment: @Did Okay, it's $ce^{t}$, which I'll now corrected, (which makes it a lot simpler) so I shall proceed.

Comment: @Did If you check my latest edit then maybe you can spot something that I can't. :/

Comment: So, considering the operator $L$ defined by $L(w)=w'''+2w''-w'-2w$, you want to find some function $w$ such that $L(w)(t)=e^t$ and you noted that $w(t)=e^t$ yields $L(w)=0$. Every set of notes that I know on the subject then suggests to compute $L(w)$ for $w(t)=te^t$, then for $w(t)=t^2e^t$, and so on.

Comment: @Did Do you mean trying $w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}$ instead?

Then I get: 

$\frac{d}{dt}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-ke^{t}

$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-2ke^{t}$

$\frac{d^{3}}{dt^{3}}w_{2}(t)_{p}=-kte^{t}-3ke^{t}

Then substituting, I get $-6ke^{t}=-2ce^{t}\iff k=\frac{c}{3}. So $w_{2}(t)_{p}=-\frac{c}{3}te^{t}.

Is that right?

Comment: This is the idea, anyhow.

Comment: @Did Check my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you introduce three new variables, $x_1$, $x_2$ and $y_2$ and set them equal to $\frac{d}{dt}w_1$, $\frac{d}{dt}w_2$ and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}w_2$ respectively, then you can write it as a system of five coupled linear differential equations. In order to do this you have to take the derivative of the second equation, rewrite it as an expression for $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}w_1$ and substitute it into the first. The first equation, with substitution, can then be rewritten as an expression for $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}w_2$, such that the two equations are only a linear combination of the two initial and the three introduced variables, without derivatives. The resulting set of equations can be written as the following five by five matrix equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
x_1\\
w_2\\
x_2\\
y_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &-1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
-1&-1& 3 & 2 &-2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
x_1\\
w_2\\
x_2\\
y_2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This can be solved by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, however this will also yields a stationary general solution, due to an eigenvalues of zero. This however does not satisfy the second equation, when also using the corresponding eigenvector and can be explained by the fact that the derivative of the second equation is used. Therefore there are only four general solutions and thus not all initial conditions can be used, which can be explained by the second equation, because it does not contain any of the highest order derivatives of $w_1$ or $w_2$.